# Unable to find regular file with default shell as bash but works when it's ksh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

We have script file *FileChecker.sh* where it checks whether file exists or not

**FileChecker.sh content:**

```
#!/bin/ksh
FILE=$1
FILE2=$2
if [[ "$FILE" == "" || "$FILE2" == "" ]] ; then
    echo "[ERROR] if Invalid input to $0 \n"
elif [[ ! -f $FILE||  ! -f $FILE2 ]] ; then
    echo "[ERROR] elif Invalid input to $0 \n"
else
   echo "In Else"
fi
```

We are logged in as user `aaa`. Running the script as follows:

```
[aaa@servername cfg]$ ./FileChecker.sh /tmp/lib/my.properties /tmp/lib/my.ear
```

and we are passing the file names with location as the input to the script and the permissions are `755` on the input files.
we ran the `FileChecker.sh` with user `aaa` and the script executed and it found the file but when we execute the `FileChecker.sh` file with user `www` then the script is unable to locate the input files and prints `[ERROR] elif Invalid input to FileChecker.sh`.

This is how I am running the script as `www`

```
/mycompany/bin/suexec -u www /tmp/cfg/FileChecker.sh /tmp/lib/my.properties /tmp/lib/my.ear
```

Following are the details about file permissions and the default Shell for both the users. default shell for `aaa` is `/bin/ksh` and for `www` it is `/bin/bash`.

```
[aaa@servername lib]$ cd /tmp/lib
[aaa@servername lib]$ ls -lrt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaagroup      175 Apr 16 11:12 my.properties
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aaa aaagroup 14354727 Apr 16 11:12 my.ear


[aaa@servername lib]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep aaa
aaa:x:129822:602:aaa, env.xyz Hostgroup, Id, F, Num:/home/aaa:/bin/ksh

[aaa@servername lib]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep www
www:x:13113:602:www, Hostgroup, Id, F, Num:/home/www:/bin/bash
```

How do I get it working by running as `www` user.

Comment: How do you run it as `www`?

Comment: I am running it like this: `/mycompany/bin/suexec -u www /tmp/cfg/FileChecker.sh`

Comment: You showed the permissions of the files in the dir `/tmp/lib`, what are the permissions of the directory ? Note that both users will run the script with `#!/bin/ksh`.

Comment: With `suexec` you are missing the arguments FILE1 and FILE2.

Comment: No, I am passing those even with `suexec`. Sorry did not mention it earlier.

Comment: got the answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512878/347509

Comment: Note that cross-posting is considered bad form -- generally, you should delete the copy on one SO site when posting on another.